# Can a Beeja Mantra be pronounced in a slightly corrupted form? Will it count as an initiation?

Tags: scripture, tantra, meditation, initiation

The modern meditation discipline of Transcendental Meditation is taught by an official teacher over a course of four or five consecutive days at the beginning of which there is a Puja of the  prominent members of the Vedantic lineage along with that of the Maharishi Mahesh Yogi and thereafter the aspirant is bestowed a mantra by the teacher and instructed to keep it a secret. The mantra, as far as [public domain expositions](http://minet.org/mantras.html) show is the exact or slightly corrupted reading of a beeja or a naama.

For example the beeja 'Hrim' is pronounced and given as 'Hirim' (most probably to make easier for a western tongue).

Though the beejas are given physically by the teacher. But as beejas are with corrupted pronounciation would such procedure count as a deekshaa? Do scriptures allow altering pronounciations of beeja mantras slightly?

Comment: I hope this course and the giving of the mantra happen over online video calls? in that case it can't be technically a Diksha. But it can be treated as an Upadesha which under some circumstances is as good as as Diksha.

Comment: @Rickross No. The student and the teacher are physically present in the same place AFAIK. Furthermore, another point of concern is that the pronunciations of certain Beejas are slightly corrupted. For example, "Hreem" has been simplified to "Hirim" or "Hiring". Can chanting these still be considered as chanting the original Beeja?

Comment: Ohh then it's ok. regarding Hrim/Hring the Bengalis pronounce the the bindu as ng instead of m. So, they pronounce Klim as Kling etc. But pronouncing Hrim as Hirim is not right. I have seen such things among people whose native language don't have yuktaksharas.

Comment: @Rickross Yes. The Beejas were probably simplified for the western tongue. Can they still be considered Beejas in this state? More specifically, do we accrue the same merits if chanting the corrupted Beeja? This should probably be an independent question in itself, but, Valmiki started with "Mara" and reached "Rama". Did the chants of "Mara" accrue any merit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 12th Patala (Chapter) of the Matrika Bheda Tantram, Goddess Chandika asks Lord Shiva that when Mantra initiation immediately results in bliss why in certain cases it results in madness and talkativeness among disciples.

To which Lord Shiva's reply is that it is due to a Dosha called "Mantracchanna". Basically there are some wrong ways of doing mantra japa that can affect the disciple in a negative way.

There are 8 kinds of Mantraccchanna doshas as given below.

> Mantracchannam pravakshyAmi srunu devi samAhitA |
> abhaktischakshare bhrAntir-luptash-chinnas-tathaiva cha ||
>  hrasvo
> dirghashcha kathanam swapne tu chAshtadhA smritah |
>  abhaktyA
> naiva siddhih syAt kalpa-kotishatairapi ||
>  Evam mantrash-chAnyathA
> vA cheti bhrAtyA cha vAtulah |
>  lupta-varne buddhinashash-chinne
> nasho bhavet kila ||
>  hrasyocchAre vyAdhi-yukto dirgha-jApe
> vasu-kshayah |
>
> Lord Shiva said:-
>
> I'm telling you what is Mantracchanata. Listen attentively. Abhakti,
> Akshara-bhrAnti, LuptatA, ChinnatA, Hrasva, Dirgha, Kathana and
> Swapna-Kathana ---- these 8 Doshas are known as MantracchanatA.
>
> (Mantra japa done with) Abhakti does not give Siddhi even in crores of
> eons; Whether the mantra is this or that --- this is called BhrAnti
> and it results in vatulatA (talkativeness).
>
> Mantra japa with Varna-lopa (alphabets missing from the mantra)
> results in loss of intelligence; with Varna-cheda (that is one Varna
> is missing from a compound Varna) results in death. If "long
> alphabets" are pronounced as "short" and vice versa that lead to
> diseases and destruction of wealth, respectively.
>
> **Sri MAtrikA Bheda Tantram; Chapter 12; Verses 42-45**

Abhakti -- lack of devotion; Akshara-BhrAnti, LuptatA, ChinnatA, Hrasva and Dirgha are  already explained; Kathana is revealing the mantra to somebody else and Swapna-Kathana is revealing the mantra in dreams to somebody else.

All these are the Doshas which render the Japa futile and affect the chanter in a negative way.

Since your only concern is about whether pronouncing Hrim as Hirim is right or not then it is not. Hrim is Ekakshara or one-letter but hirim is two-lettered. Here the compound letter Hri is missing from the mantra and new letters Hi and Ri are introduced. So, here one or more of the aforementioned Doshas are involved.